# Is a musical work bearing the name of a character from another's novel considered a derivative work

Tags: derivative-work

If a composer wanted to write a piece of music inspired by a novel written by another person, which of the following would count as a derivative work?

Setting the actual text of the book in music to be sung by a chorus would most definitely be a derivative work.  The composer would need to ask permission and share royalties, etc.  This is known and not up for debate.  But what about situations where the text is not heard in the piece, such as an instrumental work that...

> 1. Uses the main character's name in the title of the work (e.g. a string quartet titled "Holden Caulfield's Adventure") -- ignore for now how truly terrible the title is!
> 2. Uses an obvious reference to the book in the title (e.g. a solo piano piece title "Where the Ducks Go in the Winter")
> 3. Uses a generic title but includes the character's name in the dedication (e.g. a violin solo called "December" on which the first page of the printed score reads "To Holden Caulfield"

Assume both the author and composer are in the US, and assume that the book is protected by copyright and will be for a considerable amount of time.

Comment: @Jen I think that this one https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85099/how-much-names-can-be-reused-from-another-work/85104#85104 does address it.  I'll withdraw my question

Comment: This is not a duplicate o [Is the list of characters from a video game considered a fact?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86947/is-the-list-of-characters-from-a-video-game-considered-a-fact). That question and its answers deal with status of certain lists as facts and lists of facts, and the consequences of *Feist v Rural* It does not deal with derivative works at all, which is the sole issue here. However [How much names can be reused from another work?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85099/) is at least arguably a dup. The link should be repointed.

Comment: @Jen I have also flagged this. If my flag is declined I will vote reopen it, as the current association is not correct. In fact, perhaps I can do that without waiting for a moderator. I will see. (advantage of a gold tag badge). Oops this is not tagged copyright so i don't have gold-tag privileges on it.